# Using pandas, how to calculate number of columns values coming in each row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I do have a delimited file with number of columns varying in each row, i do want to create a reject and correct data delimited file based upon number of columns values in each row.
So, if

> number of headers = number of delimiter separated values in each row

it's a correct data, otherwise, it's not.
Code i have tried.

```
data = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(blob_string), sep=file_delimiter,
                  engine='python', encoding='utf-8')
data['Field_Count'] = data.notnull(axis=1)
number_of_columns = 5   


error_data = data[(data.Field_Count != int(number_of_columns))]
correct_data = data[(data.Field_Count == int(number_of_columns))]
```

But, in my case i want to calculate null fields also.

Comment: don't you get error message when you use `read_csv()` with incorrect CSV file ? As for me you should use normal `open()`, `read()`, `write()` to correct data - or even work directly with `blob_string`. And use normal `for`-loop to work with every row separatelly.